# How To Run A Python Project Using Another Project's button in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can some one help me.।
I want to open a python script using a button which is present in another python Script.।
So I want that when I click on that button my main. Py file open directly

Screensht of project 2 is given below.
I tried creating a function but not working.

Please any one help this is my college project
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atIPM.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to achieve ?

> main.py

```
import second_file

import Tkinter
import tkMessageBox

top = Tkinter.Tk()

B = Tkinter.Button(top, text ="Execute function from second file", command = second_file.my_function)

B.pack()
top.mainloop()
```

> second_file.py

```
def my_function():
  #do_stuff
```

Comment: Is there any way to open the main.py file directly without calling the function.।?